# "My answer was converted to a comment; see the faq", Okay, but what for?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, convert-to-comment

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533516/nexux-10-emulator-avd-not-running-starting#comment20705053_13533516) is the thread in question. I did some search in meta, and found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133593/what-does-your-post-was-converted-to-a-comment-mean) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118814/why-was-this-answer-converted-to-a-comment). In first of those cases the answer contains only external links, and second case, the answer was more like a suggestion and not directly answering the question. So I understood why those answers got converted as comments, but I think my answer is different. So please read fully before closing this as duplicate. I will explain from the start.

1. OP has the problem that his android Nexus 10 emulator (which he/she created using Android Eclipse AVD manager tool) was not starting up. Google doesn't provide Nexus 10 emulator as we speak with sdk, so OP manually created it using AVD Manager's Device definition section.
2. The accepted answer is kind of a negative type, saying it is not possible to start Nexus 10 emualator on a monitor which has lower resolution than targeted emulator's resolution. So it says OP's problem cannot be solved.
3. Around 2 months later, when faced with same problem, I did some searching and found the thread in question along with one other [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581548/android-how-to-create-android-emulator-for-nexus10/14153527#14153527).
4. I did some research on my own, and found out that you can make the emulator starts up by setting "**Use Host GPU**" option when creating the emulator.
5. I successfully ran the emulator created that way on lower resolution screens, so the accepted answer in the above thread is wrong.
6. So I choose one of those 2 questions, and answered it clearly with a screenshot.
7. In the other question (actually the question we are talking about), I just answered like this

   > Try and set *Use Host GPU* option when creating AVD. Please see [my
   >   answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581548/android-how-to-create-android-emulator-for-nexus10/14153527#14153527).
8. In this answer *Try and set Use Host GPU option when creating AVD* actually fully answers the question. I thought about adding screenshot here also, but decided against it. Instead I linked to the other answer where it is already explained as a screenshot.

I forgot about it, until someone's comment notified me back to the thread, and found my answer converted as a comment (and deleted), with a link to faq.

### Why should my answer get undeleted

1. The accepted answer is wrong. OP was happy with that, but it might have negative impact on future visitors.
2. I can't find anything wrong with my answer even in its current form. It completely answers the question even without the help of the link to the other answer. Link contains added information and it is not pointing to any external site.

### What I already did before asking here?

I flagged for that answer to be undeleted, with a message

> This answer should be undeleted. One reason,  the accepted answer
>   (which is of negative type saying what OP wants is not possible) is
>   wrong. OP (wrongly) accepted it and it might adversely affect future
>   visitors. Second reason my post completely answers the question even
>   without the link, and the link (which is inside stackoverflow  itself)
>   contains additional information.

I am ready to update my answer with screenshot and explanation, but I would like to know what purpose repeating an answer fully serves? Also what cause in [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) my answer invoked.

1. commentary on the question or other answers - **NO**
2. asking another, different question          - **NO**
3. “thanks!” or “me too!” responses            - **NO**
4. exact duplicates of other answers           - **I believe, this is about copying similar answer from same question. So NO**
5. barely more than a link to an external site - **NO**
6. not even a partial answer to the actual question - **NO**

Comment: I guess this is about "barely more than a link *to another Stack Overflow question*" - not sure why that's not on the list

Comment: @Pekka,  Okay, but what is the problem with linking to other stackoverflow answer (if it answers the current question)? Why repeat (copy and paste) other answers?

Comment: Pekka is right: [Answer appears automatically converted as a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment/98955#98955) explicitly states *"Trivial answers containing a link to another question in the network are automatically converted to comments on the question."*

Comment: But my post answers the question even without the link. The only negative I can find is that it only contains 1 sentence, but I don't think that is a problem here.

Comment: Stack Overflow is very unforgiving towards curt answers. That's not always fair, but most very short answers are of very low quality. I would either add a couple more words to explain, and/or copy the content from the other answer and edit it so it fits the current situation.

Comment: Well agree, I could have copy and pasted the other answer here also.. But I remember reading somewhere that it is bad to copy and paste other answers and posting as yours..Probably it was about copying other users answer.. But I had that thought in mind when I decided not to copy/paste my other answer..

Comment: But you have enough reputation to vote to close as a duplicate. Why not do that instead?

Comment: @Arjan Aaah I didn't think about it that time. Normally when I am SO'ing I put close votes. This time I was working on my project and searching to find a solution. I only bothered to answer that question because there was a wrong accepted answer. Strangely I didn't think of closing as duplicates that time..

Comment: Anyway, I edited the post and added some explanation with screenshot. The question is closed now as duplicate, so no need to undelete my answer. I put a comment under the wrong accepted answer saying the answer is plain wrong. Atleast 10k users don't have to click another link to view my answer.