# Can my answer to a question be a link to another question?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, link-only-answers

I came across a question which is indirectly related to a clearly answered questions in Stack Overflow.

Can my answer be a link to that question (all similar questions)?

Comment: Check out this new faq entry: [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer)

Comment: Actually, I am unable to comment on other questions (I think I don't have enough reputation).

Comment: Oh, I was just pointing out that post because it has a lot of detail on what an appropriate answer consists of. =)

Comment: Yeah, that post mention very clearly. thanks.

Answer (score 20):

No.

If the question is really a duplicate of another question then either flag it as a duplicate or vote to close if you have enough reputation.

If it is just related but doesn't answer the question add it as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, if

- it is not an exact duplicate of the current question. (If it is, vote to close as duplicate instead.)
- it is an essential part of your answer, which is a valid answer to the question. (If it doesn't, add the link as a comment.)

However, never just add a link. Paraphrase what the other answer says, and explain how it is connected to the current problem, and how it can be solved through it.