# I can not find question on stackoverflow.com which I answered. I also lost point that I got for accepted answer

Tags: support, reputation, lost-reputation

I answered a question on stackoverflow.com and my answer was accepted and got the reputation points for that. But after some a couple of hours those points were reduced from my reputation and I can't even find that question post as well. Why so?

Comment: The question was probably deleted or migrated.

Comment: You should be able to see the change in [your reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/948268/kuldeep-jain?tab=reputation) after checking "show removed posts" checkbox in the bottom. It should appear as -15 and say "unaccepted" or "deleted" not sure.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd good call; the actual word is "removed": `-15  1 hour ago removed Javadoc not Found`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811141/javadoc-not-found)?

Your answer was simply a link to another Stack Overflow question, not content. That is more appropriately performed as a close-duplicate vote or a comment (in fact, usually the system will detect that scenario and make it a comment automatically).

The question is now correctly closed as a duplicate.

Here is the Markdown for the deleted answer, to be clear:

```
I think you are talking about NetBeans. If yes, you may get your answer here [how-can-i-get-netbeans-to-show-me-proper-documentation-for-java-methods][1].


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812490/how-can-i-get-netbeans-to-show-me-proper-documentation-for-java-methods
```

If you are **simply** linking to an existing answer, please do so via a comment or a close-duplicate vote. It is of course perfectly acceptable to reference another post **as part of** another post, but: you must actually be adding something.

Comment: (actually, looking at the question, it looks like your answer was manually converted to a comment)

Comment: Yes I completely agree with your answer. But then Won't's answer below (in this post) should also be converted to a comment as "You should read this" is also merely a link to another Meta Stack Overflow post and has no other description. What is your say? :]

Answer (score 2):

[You should read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer)

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers.  See this meta post (especially point number 12): [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer/118694#118694)

Comment: I want to upvote for irony, but won't