# Ellipses in email subscriptions are improperly escaped

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, email-notification, encoding

I'm seeing `&hellip;` a lot in my subscription emails (see the end):

> #### [Since when is downvoting low-quality answers “abuse of the downvoting facility”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127179/since-when-is-downvoting-low-quality-answers-abuse-of-the-downvoting-facility)
>
> I posted a question on a fairly specific Java use case, and received a one-sentence answer basically of the form "what you have here is a special case of X." There wasn't any explanation of X, of why &hellip;

The relevant portion of the unformatted message:

```
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

***1 new question in [AE, M, G, L, & MSO
filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/10073/ae-m-g-l-mso) on
stackexchange.com***


[Since when is downvoting low-quality answers "abuse of the downvoting
facility"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127179/since-when-is
-downvoting-low-quality-answers-abuse-of-the-downvoting-facility)

I posted a question on a fairly specific Java use case, and received a
one-sentence answer basically of the form "what you have here is a
special case of X." There wasn't any explanation of X, of why &hellip;
```

So possibly this is something to do with the message being plaintext rather than HTML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was broken after a big refactoring of stackexchange.com's email-sending code. It's fixed now, thanks for the report.

Comment: It's still broken as of today. Is there a way I can help?