# E-mail escaping broken again

Tags: bug, email-notification, html-entities

I'm seeing `&lt;` for `<` in my, "New [topic] question for [date]", e-mails.

[image: Broken E-mail]

This seems to be a duplicate of an old issue that was marked resolved a couple years ago:  [Ellipses in email subscriptions are improperly escaped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127183/ellipses-in-email-subscriptions-are-improperly-escaped)

Comment: It still hasn't been fixed despite being reported multiple times over the years. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278234/ampersand-not-showed-correctly-in-e-mail-updates, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268897/subscription-feed-emails-doubly-encode-and-characters, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281994/why-do-email-notifications-show-html-entities-in-question-details