# Subscription feed emails doubly encode < and > characters

Tags: bug, email, email-notification, subscription

When I receive emails for my Stack Exchange email subscriptions, characters like < and > are doubly encoded, i.e., they are rendered as &lt and &gt (and encoded as `&amp;lt;` and `&amp;gt;`):

[image: screenshot of email as seen in a mail client]

Here is a sample of the source for the same email:

```
<p style="font-size:100%;color:#3d3d3d;margin-top:5px">
    I would like to change the following code so as to handle grouping of more than 1 property
    private Expression&amp;lt;Func&amp;lt;ProfileResultView, string&amp;gt;&amp;gt; DynamicGroupBy(string propertyName)
    {
         ... 
</p>
```

Comment: Agreed, this would make email notifications easier to read at a glance and thus increase likelihood of click through.

Comment: This bug has been around for years. It's hard for me to comprehend.