# Subscription feed emails still doubly encode < and > characters

Tags: bug, email-notification, subscription, html-entities

This is a re-post of [a bug from six years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268897/193205), in the hope that it will get some love.

When I receive emails for my Stack Exchange email subscriptions, characters like < and > are doubly encoded, i.e., they are rendered as &lt and &gt (and encoded as `&amp;lt;` and `&amp;gt;`), as can be seen in this email:

[image: screenshot from gmail of subscription feed summary containing doubly-encoded < and >]

Here's the actual question on SO: [How to merge two Expression<Func<T, object>>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67332000/622391)

Comment: Weird considering this one was in my email digest and it _wasn't_ "double escaped"

Comment: That's _very_ weird @ColeJohnson - I've just recreated my subscription to see if it was something related to the settings on that subscription (I've had it for a long time!)

Comment: Could it be your email viewer? As in, does this problem appear in other viewers?

Comment: No, @ColeJohnson, this happens in multiple mail clients. The screenshot comes from Gmail's web viewer.

Comment: Re-creating the subscription didn't work - I received another one today - it might set a record for incomprehensibility (due to the escaping): https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW9fa.png

Comment: It’s incredible that something as simple (AFAIK) as doubly escaping a string hasn’t been fixed in *years*.