# Ampersand not showed correctly in e-mail updates

Tags: bug, email-notification

As you can clearly see from the screenshot here below, the Ampersand char "&" is not correctly escaped in e-mail digest.
The screenshot comes from the daily update I receive from the "dnd-5e" feed of RPG.stackexchange.com .

[image: Screenshot of the received e-mail]

The paragraph should have been:
"(...) I have created my first D&D5e character (...)"

(Of course we have the same problem with the Non-breaking space)