# Why do email notifications show HTML entities in question details?

Tags: bug, email-notification

This is a rendering problem in email notifications received based on watched keywords. The text containing question details is rendered as HTML-escaped. The characters `<` (less-than) and `>` are shown as `&lt;` (ampersand-L-T-semicolon) and `&gt;`.

While it's fine to see any pre-formatted text rendered as regular text in this context, it shouldn't be HTML-escaped more than needed.

Here's a screenshot of the email in Thunderbird (Gmail shows the same):

[image: Screenshot of email in Thunderbird]

... while the question renders nicely on the website:

[image: Screenshot of the question on the website]

Comment: That's how it is in the database, if SEDE is accurate. But I still think it's a bug, since it's pretty ugly to see client-side.