# Why a flag (Not an answer) is declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021587/propertyaccessexception-while-mapping-one-to-many-mapping-between-two-classes/14037104#14037104) answer as not an answer. It was declined by a moderator with the reason:

```
declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it
```

It's very clear that the post the user has made is an edit to his question and not an answer. User himself has written that there was a typo in his question and he's just correcting it. (He might not be aware of the edit as he's a new user.)

I totally understand that the moderators review a tons of flags everyday, but this just doesn't seem like it should be kept as an answer to the question.

Should I just flag it again with same option or some other option?

PS : I've already gone through the following question, but don't find it helpful.

[Why was this flag declined consecutively?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133407/why-was-this-flag-declined-consecutively)

Comment: If that was an edit to the question, you could have asked OP to make that edit to question. Or you could have done that yourself and asked OP to delete answer.

Comment: How should I ask OP to delete the answer? By flagging only right?

Comment: @RAS The OP doesn't see flags. Only moderators do. You have well over 50 reputation required to be able to leave comments, so I'd start there. (I left a comment in this case. See my answer for more details.)

Comment: @RAS, Anna Lear has already answered your question. Check that answer.

Comment: That's called a fat finger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see how a moderator would think that this does, in fact, answer the question. I think it's unclear what's actually happening here. There are two options:

1. That is actually an answer that solves the problem. In that case, what other answer would you expect the question to get? Perhaps the question would need closing (since it was just a typo), but that wouldn't make the answer any less accurate.
2. The answer is not an answer and should've been an edit instead.

It's hard to tell which case we have on our hands here. I asked the OP to clarify... which is something you could've done as well. Commenting or correcting the situation yourself (where possible) should be your first step before flagging for a moderator.

Moderators are there to deal with situations that regular users cannot handle by themselves. For example, if you had commented on this answer asking the OP to edit but the OP didn't respond and for some reason you couldn't edit either, it'd be appropriate to flag for a moderator to ask for a conversion of the answer to an edit.

But otherwise... don't be afraid to leave comments to ask clarifying questions or suggest appropriate actions for new users who may not be aware how Stack Overflow works just yet.

Comment: I edited the post but rollbacked due to some reason. You can see its edit history. Besides, I have asked another question in comments but he has not answered yet. You can also check he has not been online for 23 hrs. That's why I flagged his answer and asked mod to do the job.