# When reviewing, what to do with short answers that could use some explanation

Tags: discussion, review

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12208479/1105376) came up in the review queue as a low quality post (no surprise there).  I'm not certain what to do with it.

1) I have no knowledge of the subject
2) It seems there could be better/more explanation, but (refer to #1) I don't have the knowledge to provide it, so editing is not one of the options for me.

Since it could be the correct answer and just needs more explanation (at least as an answer on SO) I don't think voting to delete is the proper course, but "Looks Good" seems quite inappropriate too.  Maybe "Not Sure" and leave a comment on the answer asking them to elaborate a bit?

Comment: Well that use just copied the answer from [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699757/ebean-is-not-doing-updates-its-trying-to-do-inserts-and-failing/12208479#comment15545349_11699757), so it _might_ be right.

Comment: Gah, didn't even notice that.  Still begs the question of what to do with it though.  :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the answer is probably right; the ORM needs to be notified that a database record already exists, otherwise it assumes a new record should be inserted and hence the error occurs.

Having said that, if the particular topic is not in your field of expertise the most you can probably do (unless the answer is offensive or otherwise bogus) is leave a comment to nudge the poster in improving his answer and then click `[Not sure]`.

Answer (score 1):

The first rule of thumb is: if you don't know, leave it alone.

Having said that, I believe that is an extremely bad answer. It is [just one line](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/146015), no explanation, and seems to be at odds with the title of the question:

> **Title:** EBean is not doing updates!
>
> **Answer:** You're suppose to use update()

An educated guess would tell me that the OP has probably tried a few obvious things, given the level of detail in their question. For this one I would suggest you down vote it and flag it as not an answer, whatever is available to you.