# Where can I find why my answer was deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Where can I find the reason my answer was deleted?

My answer to: [PHP autocomplete in Eclipse PDT function documentation not formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895956/php-autocomplete-in-eclipse-pdt-function-documentation-not-formatted) has been deleted without any reason.

The other answer on the question has nothing to do with the question itself and it's allowed...

Comment: The other answer is not and never was accepted, nor does it have any votes...

Comment: @ani - by accepted I think the OP means was not deleted... The other question was "*allowed*".

Comment: It's true, my mistake. I just find strange that giving a solution gets deleted and saying try another software no...

Comment: BTW, you can find why your answer was deleted right here. You've come to the right place! We can help you understand why it *might* have been deleted, but only the moderator who executed the deletion will be able to tell you for sure.

Comment: I'd suggest you read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer then edit your answer to improve it.  Flag it to have it undeleted when you're done.  You're right about the other answer.  Its now gone.

Comment: @ricardgf You've edited it to the point where it's more useful.  I've undeleted it.  Note that if this is accepted as the answer, it might be considered "too localized", but that's a fault with the question, and not your answer.

Comment: I couldn't ask the OS since I can't post comments... May I ask why is too localized?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your answer doesn't actually explain *how* to take the steps. Here is the entirety of your deleted answer (when it was deleted):

> Are you using linux? I've solved it installing libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 in ubuntu.

That's a question (or a comment), not an answer.

You edited it to be:

> There is a missing library. In linux you can solve it by installing libwebkitgtk-1.0-0.

This is still useless.  If the user doesn't know how to install `libwebkitgtc-1.0-0`, this is only going to have them ask more questions.  We want answers to be complete and useful on their own.  At this stage, your answer is not.

To get it undeleted, I recommend:

- Include steps for the specific version of linux the user uses (does *every* distro use `apt-get` now?)
- Be complete. Think the way a googler would. Would you want to have to bounce around to 5 different sites to get your question answered? I wouldn't.

Comment: -1 I disagree with the notion that it's the answerer's responsibility to include steps to install a package or library, specially if no distro is specified in the question. Besides, installing a package in their distro is something everyone should know how to do.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ "It's broken, you fix it by Fooing the widget." "How do I foo the widget?"  That's the problem.  It may be turtles all the way down, but without giving complete answers, we risk having our answers be as useless as forum answers. Do you remember those days? Where you needed to bounce around to 10 different forums to answer one problem because they all had a piece? I do. Those days sucked. Let's not repeat them.

Comment: Because we all know if they were using Windows, you would tell them how to download the msi, find the folder it was downloaded to, double click on the msi, click 'Next', click 'Next', click 'Next', click 'Finish'.

Comment: Like you said, it's turtles all the way down. It seems rather draconian to just draw an arbitrary line in the sand and say, "a (useful) answer needs *this* much information to be useful, otherwise I'll delete it."

Comment: @Null: I believe that was what community voting/moderation was designed for. If the answer was not sufficient, it would not be rated highly among better answers thereby encouraging the answerer to edit their answer and improve it.

Comment: I've edited the anwer to be more techie, now I can't flag the answer again.

Comment: @ricardgf Yea, you can only flag an answer once. Use it wisely. :-) I used to get around that by flagging the question but referencing the answer. not altogether the best idea, but in very limited circumstances it works.

Answer (score 5):

My best guess was it was deleted because it began with asking a question for clarification (which should usually be a comment instead), and it was very short. I see you edited it to remove the initial question, although the answer is still very short.

Personally, I would vote to undelete it if I could. If you've encountered the same problem in the past, chances are your solution will fix the problem, and as someone posting the question, I would much rather have one possible answer instead of none.

My best advice would be to try and make the answer a bit longer by clarifying that you've encountered this problem in the past, as that will back up your claim that the install will fix the problem, and if possible provide a link to the library you mention. Something like:

> I've encountered this issue in the past and have solved it by
>   installing
>   [libwebkitgtk-1.0-0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libwebkitgtk-1.0-0). I am using linux / ubuntu, and it appears this library is missing by default.

**Edit:** Nevermind, I see you already did a much better edit than that which actually explains the problem in more detail :)