# Am I plagarising by summarizing a duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I came across this question today: [Getting Parent Element Width for Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16614486/211627)

While writing my answer, I came across this earlier question: [Why ActualSize is not updating its value on WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008525/why-actualsize-is-not-updating-its-value-on-wpf)

On the surface it looks a little different, but it's actually the same problem from two perspectives. I ended up summarizing the accepted answer, with heavy attribution, including a little additional information, then voting to close the question as a duplicate.

The question is whether or not I should have posted the answer in the first case? I ended up summarizing someone else's answer plus I don't know what the policy is on answering a question you intend to vote to close. I ended up deciding to post my answer because I was concerned that the OP might not see the connection immediately.

Comment: UPDATE: As per [Servy's guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180713/191410), I've deleted my answer and explained the connection in a comment.

Comment: See #6 on the [What is an acceptable answer? Faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118582/148672)

Comment: I can see your deleted answer, and I definitely don't think it's plagiarism and have voted to undelete it. Plagiarism means you copy/paste someone else's work, and claim it as your own. In your case, you're attributing the work correctly to the original author, and providing other content as well, such the stuff from the official documentation. In addition, you went out of your way to use your own words and summarize the content so it specifically applies to the OP's question. That is definitely not plagiarism, and deserves some rep in my book :)

Comment: @Rachel - I appreciate that, but I deleted it because I think the question is a duplicate and, as per Servy (and #6 on the acceptable answer FAQ), I was able to summarize why I think it's a duplicate within the confines of a comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not be both voting to close the question and answering it.  If you're voting to close it means that you don't think the question should be answered, if you're answering you obviously feel it should be.

> I ended up deciding to post my answer because I was concerned that the OP might not see the connection immediately

If the questions are different enough that this is the case then it's appropriate to post an answer.  If you do so then you shouldn't be voting to close; you're asserting they're different questions.

In some borderline cases you could also consider just posting a comment in addition to the proposed dupe link that explains the "missing link" between the two questions.  If you can't explain why the other question is a dupe in the scope of a comment then they probably aren't dups; post an answer that refers to the related (but not duplicate) question and explain how that solution can be applied to this problem.  Conversely, if you can explain why the other question is the same in the scope of a comment, they are duplicates.

With respect to the "am I plagarising" the answer is, no, so long as you attribute appropriately.  All content on SE sites are under the [CC-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license as well, meaning they can be reproduced anywhere so long as they are appropriately attributed.

Comment: +1, "if they're different enough [someone might not see the connection]".

Comment: @DaveNewton Not just the OP even, but any reader.

Comment: So, if your answer is essentially a link to another answer and explaining the connection, would that mean the question is a duplicate? Or does the need to explain the connection mean they are different enough that it's not a duplicate?

Comment: @Cyborgx37 `"If you can't explain why the other question is a dupe in the scope of a comment then they probably aren't dups"`  Conversely, if you *can* explain why the other question is the same in the scope of a comment, they are duplicates.

Comment: "If you're voting to close it means that you don't think the question should be answered, if you're answering you obviously feel it should be." What about the case of a question that should be closed and deleted as 'too localized' as it won't help any future SO users, but you may as well answer it because it's a quick easy answer?

Comment: @Patashu A question like that shouldn't even be _asked_, and by extension shouldn't be answered.

Comment: @Patashu You should close it as too localized and not answer it.  Answering it encourages people to continue asking it because they'll know that they'll be answered even if it gets closed.  That's harmful to the site's goals of creating widely applicable high quality programming information.

Answer (score 5):

If it's a duplicate, it's a duplicate: unless there's a specific reason to differentiate your answer, mark to close, and don't answer.

That said, it's often a fine line between making sure the *specific* question is answered if there's any thinking involved in utilizing the "duplicate", both because sometimes thinking is hard, and because "making the leap" can be dependent on a multitude of factors.

Comment: Nope, user gets rep for summarizing a dupe answer.  Not really fair to tell OP to pass up available rep.

Comment: @djechlin "Fair"?! That aside, IMO polluting SO with legitimate dupes does nothing but add useless noise. If it's really the same question, we don't need the same answer said another way-that's abusive. If it's different enough to be confusing, as I said, answer it.

Comment: Problem is we 1) don't incentivize finding dupes and 2) incentivize not finding dupes.  It's a broken system and to my knowledge the highest upvoted feature request that's not done yet, but rep = incentive is the rule on SO, so that perverse incentive needs to be fixed before we can honestly recommend users to listen to us, not what awards rep.

Comment: I mean I do my best on meta.SO to get users to participate constructively, but I can't really fight TPTB creating perverse incentives when everyone on meta has screamed at them to fix this.  So, until then, happy duplicate answer reaping, everyone.

Comment: @djechlin I don't find that (a) no explicit punishment for not doing what's right, and (b) no explicit reward for doing what's right a sufficient excuse. That said, I fully recognize that I hold people to higher standards than most are capable of.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't think it's as black and white as you're making out - the rep system; the badges: all of this nudges the multitude of users who pass through the site to behave in a particular way.  I think looking at this type of thing from the perspective of an individual user is flawed - better to look at it like water flowing through a pipe - small changes to the pipe make changes to the flow.  Any individual molecule is largely irrelevant.

Comment: @GHC I agree 100%--and to me that strengthens what I said, in at least two ways.