# Does this answer "look good"?

Tags: discussion, review, answers, low-quality-posts

How would you vote in a Low Quality review task? Please explain.

The reason I'm asking is because I often face this kind of answer and I'm not sure how are we supposed to review them.

Link: [Auto Layout: Toolbar not shown, container views distorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835118/auto-layout-toolbar-not-shown-container-views-distorted/18835558#18835558)

Comment: Better than "Have you tried adding `height` constraint on your toolbar?"

Comment: There's an Objective-C tag, but no code. There's nothing in the question that would enable anyone to reproduce the problem -- so the answers are going to be guesses.

Comment: @user814064 All the more reason to add options to review the question too. Sometimes a low quality answer is indicative of a poor question that needs to be closed, but you can't really do anything from the review item itself. (Though, I can't judge this question fairly because I know nothing about it.)

Comment: See #10 on [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/191410)

Answer (score 5):

It's an attempt to answer the question, so it's not "not an answer".

The OP has commented indicating it didn't solve his problem.  Not knowing anything about the subject material it's not clear if the answer is just off base, just doesn't include enough information for the OP to properly use it, or if the answer truly is the proper solution to such a problem.  Depending on which of these is the case, someone with sufficient knowledge about the domain may or may not choose to downvote the post based on its technical merits.

The post is certainly lacking in detail, but if that actually was all that was missing additional detail would be nice, but not needed.  It is up to you to decide if you think enough detail is lacking to downvote.  I certainly don't think enough detail is lacking to justify deletion.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. It should really be a comment. For the one liner to qualify as an answer then code must be present.

**One line suggestions are not answers.**

It was brought up that rule #10 of the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/191410) applies. As a result of there being no code in that answer, this rule does not apply. The answer applies to #2 of the FAQ linked because it is a one line suggestion, in which case the action suggested is flag as not an answer.

Further, this is not applicable to rule #10 as the suggestion is not a solution to the question. It is merely a shot in the dark. These add clutter to the site, and you can see them strewn around with negative votes on all sorts of posts. The low quality of a one line guess with no code as an answer cannot be overstated.

Comment: But moderators cannot judge the content, and there is clearly content. The answerer recommends setting a particular attribute to a particular value which *is* coding advice (though it may not contain a code snippet). #2 seeks feedback from the OP, but this answer is not asking a question - it is attempting to provide a solution. I disagree with your reasoning.

Comment: It is not a question, thus it clearly is not of the same form of the second example in your link.  It turns out that the answer doesn't work, but it's still an answer.  It's not a quality answer, and as such downvoting it may be appropriate, but it's an *attempt* to answer the question, and as such it is most certainly not NAA.  A "too short" answer isn't NAA.  It may be very low quality, possibly low enough quality to warrant deletion (although I don't think so in this case) but so long as it's an attempt at an answer, it's not NAA.

Comment: [cough cough](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10199426/119477) [Ahem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8921101/119477)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter - in all fairness, we all make mistakes and learn to do better. I have advocated against behaviors of which I was once guilty. :)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter - Thank you for pointing out some of my answers which should be deleted or edited. Those were when I was relatively new to the site. I agree that they are not answers as you imply.

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 - I do not believe there is content in the answer. Note that the answer in question was self deleted already. When you say content, the only thing you are specifically referring to in this instance is the word "height" with regards to "container". The answer could easily be prefaced with the word "try".

Comment: @Servy - The format more closely matches "try this" than "here is the code". As a result, it is not an answer to the question but a suggestion. There are plenty of attempts to answer questions which are deleted, that it was an attempt really has no impact on the outcome of the answer posted - which was in fact a single line suggestion with no code, explanation, or specifics.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter - What do you think of these: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3419816/1026459), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3313436/1026459), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3692746/1026459)?

Comment: @TravisJ - Posts from 2010? The FAQ article wasn't even written until 2012. So how long must an answer be to qualify? If it contains an actual solution which helps the user and future visitors but can be said in 100 characters without the need for code formatting, would you delete it? Your answer is too broad and does not conform to existing norms. By your criteria, many answers in the [tag:regex] tag should be deleted (even though they've been accepted and upvoted, indicating they were helpful and useful).

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 - Content should be maintained. The date posted is irrelevant unless there is historical significance. The answer I deleted was a suggestion, and was only 1 line. It had a vote so does that mean it contained an actual solution and helped future visitors? I understand that your position is to take the recently written FAQ article as the status quo and defend it, but saying that it was only written recently and does not apply to previous posts is hypocritical. If a real solution is less than 100 characters, the question is probably low quality. If not, the answer probably is.

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 - The regex tag has had many conversations about what to do with one line answers. There is no blanket, one size fits all solution to an answer's content length. However, I believe it must be at least 30 characters at present. Flagging an answer as not an answer is something which depends on context. In my opinion, if you understand the context, and recognize a suggestion which requires clarification to stand as an answer, it should be flagged as not an answer and migrated to a comment.

Comment: @TravisJ I was having a bit of fun I think you took it too seriously. Personally I don't like hard and fast rules like this because they have a tendency to destroy useful content. For example Posting a blank form to force a refresh sounds like a good idea to me. Do we really need more than that? I guess `document.forms[""].submit();` would have been nice (is that correct? I'm not a JS guy.)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter - I don't mind having my content reviewed, I did actually appreciate the opportunity to look at it. Your js suggestion would work just fine :) But the reason I removed the answer is because the question was asking for a way with javascript disabled to refresh the page, and I don't think there is a way to automate the blank form posting so I removed the answer.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter - As for the hard fast rules. I posted this as an answer hoping to have the position vetted. I do like to see both sides of arguments and so I decided to take the position that these short answers are not answers because that was my take on it. I am willing to change my view, but am still curious as to when these short one liners are actually contributing. As you pointed a few of my own out, I could see that in my opinion my answers there did not add value to the question.

Comment: If I were to suggest a rule of thumb, I'd say that it would be acceptable to delete a one-liner answer if the content within that answer is duplicated by another longer answer which fleshes out the idea more thoroughly (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9758/191410). However, a one-liner answer should be allowed to stand if it at least contains a practical suggestion and there are no other answers with that same suggestion. It may help to point a future visitor in the right direction. There is a possibility that someone else (perhaps the OP) will edit it into a more appropriate answer later.