# "Asking for clarification" flag is declined?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19959584/1149495) as "not an answer", since it asks for clarification instead of answering the question. However, this flag is declined as "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

Did I do something wrong and are this type of answers correct nowadays?

Comment: It has an implied "[You should try] with an absolute path for the "target_path"". Still a terrible answer, but it is sort of, kind of, on the very edge of being an answer

Comment: That's not a request for clarification. That's a suggestion.

Comment: If this is an acceptable answer than #2 on [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/148672) needs to be updated

Comment: I recently flagged [this vim answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15064740/656243) as not an answer, too... since it was so off topic, that it wasn't just wrong, but just,.. well, not an answer. That flag was declined, too (albeit as "but found no evidence to support it").

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I've always taken the approach of making suggestions as comments, and if they work, write an answer. If I'm sure that the answer isn't going to garner negative rep (read: it's correct and answers the question), I'll forgo the comment, but those answer won't engage the OP as a question.

Comment: @Lynn Crumbling: Yes, ideally you'll want to post it as a comment because it would suck as an answer, but it's still kinda sorta an answer...

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter That #2 is somewhat unclear on if in "Have you fooed the baz?"  whether fooing the baz could solve the problem or is a debugging step (like have you read the stack trace?)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Also, there are some strange points in that answer. Apparently "The accepted answer is incorrect or no longer accurate." shouldn't be flagged as NAA

Comment: @RichardTingle You think wrong answers should be flagged instead of downvoted?

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter "The accepted answer is incorrect or no longer accurate." doesn't attempt to answer the question

Comment: [related](http://i.stack.imgur.com/An1s1.png)

Comment: @RichardTingle I'm pretty sure if you flag a wrong answer NaA you'll get declined with *flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer* But feel free to give it a shot.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter That answer seems to flip back between you **think** "xyz" and someone has **written** "xyz". I am interpreting that one as **written** but considering it the other way the whole answer becomes inconsistent and confusing

Answer (score 3):

> Have you tried XYZ?

is in every day speech equivalent to

> You should try XYZ if you haven't already

All answers have an implied "if you haven't already" so we can say it's equivalent to

> You should try XYZ

So the implied answer was

> [You should try] with an absolute path for the "target_path"

Which is a terrble terrible answer, but it is an answer none the less.

Answer (score 1):

That's a comment; not an answer.

It certainly is asking for clarification, and even if it is the "answer" it is so short that it is begging for some additional supporting explanation.